# How to sum differences in adjacent values of list of times ("time clock")?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm querying my database to get the list of "events" such as punch in, start break, end break, punch out for an employee. Now I need to sum the difference between each adjacent pair, for example: totalTime=(t4-t3)+(t2-t1) and I can't seem to get my head around it :(

What I've tried so far is:

```
TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();

for (int i = 0; i < worked.Count - 1; i++)
{
    totalTime = totalTime.Add(worked[i + 1].Time - worked[i].Time);
}
```

Which is giving me (not surprisingly) the total of the difference in each successive pair, so: `totalTime = (t4 - t3) + (t3 - t2) + (t2 - t1)`.

Sorry, I guess I'm overtired but drawing a blank.

Comment: So you want to increment the loop by two on each iteration?

Comment: If they are guaranteed to always come in pairs, in your iterator simply change `i++` to `i += 2`

Comment: … Oh my God, you won't believe what I was doing.  I was changing the increment in the wrong place.  Time to call it a day.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you're overtired, get some sleep! :D

Assuming that you can reliably say that your array contains successive clock-in/clock-out pairs (or similar, e.g. paired "enter/exit", "start/stop" times, etc.), you can also assume that the array has an even number of entries (or, in the worst case, if there is an odd entry at the end that you don't care about it).

In this case you just need to skip by 2:

```
TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();

for (int i = 0; i < worked.Count - 1; i += 2) // Notice we're incrementing by 2 now
{
    totalTime = totalTime.Add(worked[i + 1].Time - worked[i].Time);
}
```

This obviously falls over miserably if you have mismatched pairs: say someone forgets to clock out or clocks out twice, or the query you're using happens to select a "clock out" as the first time, followed by the next "clock in" - in which case you'll be measuring the time ***between*** clocked-in times.  Just be very careful about the data you're fetching.

If there's a way to fetch into separate arrays for clock-ins and clock-outs, that would make for a far more robust solution, but the time aggregation gets a lot harder because you have to design specific rules about what happens if particular events are missing or in multiples.  But that's a discussion for another question, should it come to that.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed... please don't ding me and pretend you didn't see this thread.
I'm going home.  Thank you!

Comment: I will say, in all humility, I did come up with a nice solution to your concern (which I shared).  I show hide buttons corresponding to the next "event".  If you're clocked in, the only buttons available are clock out, start break etc.  Other than miscalculating the time of course ;)

Comment: OK, but don't underestimate users.  They'll probably still find a way to break it: if your program crashes and they restart, will it pick up the correct state? If I clock in just before going home for the day and clock out when I get in the next morning, then realise what I've done and clock in again: if you select all the clock times for the day it now begins with a clock-out instead of a clock-in.  But think on that more after you've got some sleep :D

Comment: From what I gather, that's a common problem to all these systems.  The typical scenario is the bookkeeper manually editing the entries (and setting a flag of course that it's been edited) so the employee sees they never clocked out last night... they clock out, then clock back in and notify the office... or something like that.  But you're right, a discussion for another, more rested time ;)

Thanks again!